# How to Use $gte and &lte mongo operator if date is in ISODate format in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.claimPaymentLog.find({"claimDate":{"$lte":{"sec":1579046400,"usec":0}}})
```

I have claimDate field like `{"claimDate":{"$lte":{"sec":1579046400,"usec":0}}` in database. Now I want to perform `$gte` and `&lte` on claimDate field that is in string format like below :

**My code :**

```
  $start = new MongoDate(strtotime("2020-01-15 00:00:00"));
  $this->_collection->find({"claimDate":{"$lte":$start}});
```

Comment: What seems to be the the issue with using `$gte` and `$lte`?

Comment: @Manish Solanki : what language are you using ?